# How can I list all event listeners used by movie

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to see / debug all my event listeners because when I test the swf on a server, Comodo Dragon browser is behaving strangely after I play with the movie some time.

I'm using Flash Professional CC 2014. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have the original `fla` file? I think your question is very much like the one I asked earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964061/how-to-display-events-sent-from-actionscript-to-embedding-container

Comment: yes I have the original file. i edited the title

Comment: When then you could use something like `Flash CS4`, `Flash Professional CS5`, `FlashDevelop`, etc to debug your application. Here is an article about debugging in as3: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_as3_debugging.html

Comment: In addition, because you said "after I play with the movie some time" that to me sounds like some potential memory issues. You may also want to use Scout https://creative.adobe.com/products/scout   And depending on your resources you may want to use Monster Debugger http://demonsterdebugger.com/